# Unsigned float in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

How to have a unsigned float data type in python - sqlalchemy framework?

I am using Integer type, which results in a `Warning: Out of range value for column 'xxxx' at row 1 cursor.execute(statement, parameters)`.

I am implementing the table like this :

```
class testTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    xxxx = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('another.id'))
    yyyy = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    .
    .
    .
```

MySQL is the database server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float) reveals there is the `Float` type.

```
from sqlalchemy import Float

(...)

class testTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    xxxx = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('another.id'))
    yyyy = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    zzzz = Column(Float)
```

For MySQL specifics such as `unsigned`, refer to [the respective documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.FLOAT), e.g. importing the specific UPPERCASE types:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import FLOAT
```

You can then use these to create your Column as usual:

```
zzzz = Column(FLOAT(unsigned=True))
```

Comment: I am looking for unsigned float

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already went through that link and that section. Need to know how to implement it.

Comment: @Vijay47 I guess it is somewhat easy to miss, see edit.

Comment: `from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import FLOAT` will import the FLOAT type as unsigned?

Comment: @Vijay47 It will import the FLOAT type specific to the mysql dialect, you can then create your `Column` with the appropriate options, e.g. `unsigned=True`, `zerofill=True` and such.

Comment: `zzzz = Column(Float(unsigned=True))` like this?. thanks for the replies

Comment: @Vijay47 You have to make sure to use `FLOAT` with uppercase, but yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This really helped me